# How to show that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}e^x \sin(\tan x)dx \geq 1+e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-1\right)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

**Question:**

**To prove:**

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}e^x \sin(tanx)dx \geq  1+e^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-1\right)$

**My attempt:**

Since,

Integrand is monotonic increasing in interval $0$ to $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ so, i can use

$m.\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-0\right)\leq\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}f(x)dx\leq M.\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-0\right)$ where, m and M are global  minima and maxima in the given interval

$0\leq\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}e^x \sin(tanx)dx\leq e^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}\sin(1)  $

After this I don't know how to proceed further. I am only aware about above inequality and Cauchy Schwarz inequality but unable to solve it using both methods . Any help would be appreciated . Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

It is sufficient to prove that, in the considered interval,
$$\sin (\tan (x)) > x$$

Using Taylor expansion built at $x=0$, we have
$$\sin (\tan (x))=x+\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{40}-\frac{55 x^7}{1008}-\frac{143
   x^9}{3456}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$

Then
$$\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}e^x \sin(\tan(x))\,dx >\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}x \,e^x\,dx $$ and one integration by parts will give the result.

In fact, you could even prove that
$$x < \sin (\tan (x)) < x+\frac{x^3}{6}$$ making
$$1+\frac{1}{4} e^{\pi /4} (\pi -4)<\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}e^x \sin(\tan(x))\,dx <2+\frac{1}{384} e^{\pi /4} \left(-768+192 \pi -12 \pi ^2+\pi ^3\right)$$

Numerically, the left bound is $0.529318$, the right bound is $0.559271$ and the numerical integration gives $0.554285$.

Comment: @FaradayPathak. In fact, it is "amazing" to notice that, up to $O(x^25)$, all coefficients are negative.

Comment: yes . got it .thanks

Comment: Just the Taylor expansion with the remainder in the big-O form doesn't prove the inequality on the whole interval though.